# Xamarin.forms iOS webview not opening Payment Gateway

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.ios

I have a xamarin.forms ios app which contains a webview. My webview loads fine until there will be a button in my webpage which will redirect to a PayU payment page. The page will load fine on an android webview (NB: The android app is done using android studio). But in my xamarin.forms ios app nothing loads when we click the specific button in the loaded webview. What will cause this issue?

NB: The webpage and payment URL loads properly on safari and chrome.

I have used the hybridwebview https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview . But nothing changed.

I have added

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>example.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

because I am using HTTP for my web URL. How can I solve the issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share us a test link so that we can test it on my side? Usually set NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = true is enough to load http urls.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Hi, will                 <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
  cause any unwanted issues related to payment URL?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Bro the payment URL is https://www.payumoney.com/citruspage/ is this and it will redirect to  https://checkout.citruspay.com/ with some unique id

Comment: You don't need to set NSExceptionDomains. Just use `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>`.